# Change keyboard animation duration when tapping on UITextField

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, animation, uitextfield

Hi there,

I am trying to reduce / increase the keyboard animation duration when tapping on a `UITextField`.
I tried different things, but I couldn't manage to achieve my goal :

1. I tried to set the animation duration inside the `textFieldShouldBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) -> Bool`, but I got an infinite loop as I try to call `textField.becomeFirstResponder()` which calls again `func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) -> Bool` etc...
2. I set the animation in a method triggered when the keyboard is going to show ( responding to the `NSNotification` whose name is `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` ) but it looks like it's too late
3. I was thinking about adding a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to my `UITextField` which would trigger the animation but I am affraid that it would conflict with the native `UITextField`'s gesture recognizer

When I say "trigger the animation", I mean doing something like that :

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(10.0, animations: {
            textField.becomeFirstResponder()
        })
```

I don't really know what to do now, it seems pretty tricky to change this animation duration.

Any suggestions would be really appreciated :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple solution, override the becomeFirstResponder, just remember to do some checking.

Example.

```
class MyTextField: UITextField{

    override func becomeFirstResponder() -> Bool {
        // guard clause
        if(!self.canBecomeFirstResponder()) { return false }

        UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, animations: {
            super.becomeFirstResponder()
        })

        return true;
    }
}
```

Just modify the animation parameters to anything u like and replace your TextField with This MyTextField.

Comment: Why are you delaying the super call to next runloop? `becomeFirstResponder` is (or should be) only called on main thread.

Comment: It should be running on main thread but weird, last time i tried, it was running on the other thread and throw warning.

And i try again it's running on main thread now.

in this case, won't need dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue())

Comment: code updated, thanks for reminding. tested when it's triggering from
1. user tap on textfield
2. call textfield.becomeFirstResponder (works with or without animation block)

Comment: If you call `becomeFirstResponder`/`resignFirstResponder` in your code, you have to take extra care to call it on the main thread. Perhaps this was your issue.

Comment: That's a perfectly working solution, thanks @Codebear